# A Question about the "Blender resources" question

Tags: discussion

Should there be in that list of resources a heading for forums and similar groups? I don't want to add one without some discussion about it first.

Comment: Sounds good to me

Answer (score 5):

It is a community wiki, as such please add any info and resources you find that fit in to the categories that are already there (and there is no need to ask first to do so).

However if you want to add a new category (such as reference images), or restructure the answers that are there (say merge blogs and community sites <sub>which I think would be a good idea</sub>), please ask on the meta first.

To answer you question.
Yes a general blender sites answer is a good idea.
It could contain blogs, tutorial sites, forum(s), etc.

Thank you for making the [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/2217) list better.

Comment: Well, after gandalf3's comment, I kind of jumped right in, after which Gandalf3 did a masterful job of organizing the original question, at least in my view..

Comment: @brasshat I saw, and you did a good job.

Comment: I'm not so sure about good; I was aiming for "reasonably tolerable".

Comment: @brasshat lol, it was much better then that.